# Replace values of a list of lists with values of another different list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am wondering if I can replace values of a list of lists with values of another list in Python:

let's say

```
W = [[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]

V = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I am wondering if I can replace values of W with values of V, in such a way that it becomes like below:

```
W = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: w = [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    z = 0
    for i in w:
        x = 0
        while x < len(i):
            i[x] = v[z]
            x += 1
            z += 1

    print(w)   So sad this was a very fun question the setup and desire results were tricky, but this is a for loop to solve this, you will have to reformat it

Answer (score 4):

You can use `iter`:

```
W = [[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
V = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
v = iter(V)
new_w = [[next(v) for _ in i] for i in W]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: While this makes sense and is the most concise solution, it seems like a waste to create an array of zeros only to throw it away in a subsequent operation.

Comment: @coldspeed Unless the OP truly wishes to mutate `W` in place, it seems that the latter is being used purely to structure the final output.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `V` into an iterator, slice with `itertools.islice` and assign back to `W`:

```
from itertools import islice
it = iter(V)
for i in W:
    i[:] = islice(it, len(i))
```

```
print (W)
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I like this because it updates `W` in place without creating a new list.